# how to give permission accessing a routes according to custom permission in vue.js?

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2

i have five classes. as example class 1 to class 5.Admin  assigning student to different class from Admin Dashboard.what i want is if student doesn't have access of a particular class  student will not able to access to class component.

Answer (score 0):

in vue js the easiest way is by using the meta tag on the route so:

```js
{
   path: "/only-students-from-class-a",
   meta: {studentClass: 'a'}
}
```

And then with a global router guard check if the current user belongs to the class that's stored in the meta before you let the user actually see the page.

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const userClass = store.state.user.studentClass;
  if (to.meta.studentClass && userClass !== to.meta.studentClass) 
      next('/login')
  else next()
})
```

You can also do this on a route basis:

```js
{
      path: '/foo',
      component: Foo,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
       const studentClass = store.state.user.studentClass;
       if(studentClass !== 'class5') next('/login')
       else next();
      }
}
```